# Typegoose find() on model does not return reference array fields

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, typegoose

i am inserting data into mongodb with this Model:

```
export class Mapresult extends Typegoose {
    @prop()
    match_id: string;

    @prop()
    map: string;

    @prop({ ref: Team })
    winner?: Ref<Team>;

    @prop()
    demo_link: string;

    @prop({ ref: Team })
    public teams?: Ref<Team>[];

    @prop({ ref: Teamresult })
    public team_results?: Ref<Teamresult>[];
}
export const MapresultModel = new Mapresult().getModelForClass(Mapresult);
```

and am populating teams and team_results later.

In the mongodb webinterface, both prop arrays have values: [screenshot of mongodb entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OfRk.png)

But when i run

```
MapresultModel.findOne({ match_id: req.params.match_id, map: req.params.map_name })
    .then((result) => {
        return result.populate("winner").populate("teams").populate("team_results").execPopulate();
    })
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result);
    });
```

the result i am receiving is:

```
{
    _id: 5f9843e2915f421a1866b822,
    match_id: '1-96be1535-8671-4790-80ac-2bbcf1f8dfa2',
    map: 'de_overpass',
    demo_link: 'https://demos-europe-west2.faceit-cdn.net/csgo/4bcc5d50-e5c6-4510-a0df-1430774482af.dem.gz',
    __v: 0,
    winner: {
        _id: 5f9843e2915f421a1866b81d,
        myid: '069f67d6-a217-4635-9618-a2e8882fc678',
        name: 'GoPott',
        team_logo: 'https://assets.faceit-cdn.net/teams_avatars/069f67d6-a217-4635-9618-a2e8882fc678_1581456059302.jpg',
        __v: 0
    }
```

}

And as you can see, `winner` is being populated, while `teams` and `team_results` are not in the result. Even before populating, these props are not in the result.

How do i get `teams` and `team_results` to be in the result?

Comment: What happens if you do `result.populate({ path: "winner teams team_results" })` instead of chaining them?

Comment: still the same. `teams` and `team_results` are still missing. I'm suspecting that the problem is not the population, but within the `.findOne()` call.

Comment: Agreed, what does `result` look like when you enter the first `.then()`? before population, have you logged it to see what properties are on it?

Comment: The only difference in the result is, that the `winner` field contains a ObjectId instead of the values from above. The 2 missing fields are still missing

Comment: Do the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097980/mongoose-with-typegoose-returns-null-for-reference-with-valid-objectid) fix the problem for you? Looks like if you are populating multiple items, you need to include the model on the populate?

Comment: Nope, didn't make a difference. Like I said, I don't think that populate is the problem here. The props aren't even returned by the `findOne()` call.

Comment: Ii'm not sure then, I'm sorry. We may need more details or a reproducible example to further help you

Comment: as i can see in the usage of `extends Typegoose` and `.getModelForClass`, please try to upgrade to 7.4 (`@typegoose/typegoose`) and report back -- did you already try logging with `virtuals: true` just in case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the Typegoose version. I was using `@hasezoey/typegoose` which was on version 5.9. The right package is `@typegoose/typegoose` with version ^7.4.1. Fix all the errors after updating the typegoose version and it should work.